# How do you create objects that have an instance pointer of itself in a loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, object, stdvector

I have the following class:

```
class Worker
{
private:
    const int m_id;
    Worker* m_partner = nullptr;
public:
    Worker(const int &id)
        :m_id(id){}

    Worker(const int &id, Worker partner)
        :m_id(id)
    {
        m_partner = &partner;
    }
}
```

When I create a vector of workers like this:

```
std::vector<Worker> workers;
workers.push_back(Worker(0, Worker(1)));
workers.push_back(Worker(2, Worker(3)));
workers.push_back(Worker(4, Worker(5)));
```

I get a good vector of worker-partner objects, with ids 0-1, 2-3 and 4-5. How can I create this in a for loop? When I try this:

```
for (int id = 0; id < 6; id += 2)
{
    workers.push_back(Worker(id, Worker(id+1)));
}
```

all main workers are being partnered with partner 5, a.k.a. the last partner worker object created. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the constructor:

```
Worker(const int &id, Worker partner)
```

You define the argument `partner` as a *local variable*, and its life-time will end (and the object be destructed) when the function returns. This means any pointer to this variable will become invalid as soon as the constructor function returns.

You need to pass this argument either by reference or as a pointer (and the original object needs to stay alive and valid as long as the `Worker` object you create lives).

---

If you the object you pass to the constructor won't be alive long enough (as in the example in the question) then you need to make a *copy* of the `partner` object:

```
Worker(const int id, Worker partner)
    : m_id(id), m_partner(std::make_unique<Worker>(std::move(partner)))
{
}
```

<sub>[Note that the `id` argument doesn't need to be passed by reference]</sub>

Instead of using plain pointer I recommend you use *smart* pointers, like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). Then you won't have to worry about needing your own copy-constructor, destructor or such:

```
std::unique_ptr<Worker> m_worker;
```

This will make `Worker` objects impossible to copy. If you need copying then use `std::shared_ptr` (and `std::make_shared`) instead.

Comment: That alternative isn't going to work. The class `Worker` can't have a `Worker` as a member variable.

Comment: @NathanPierson I think it's time for bed now... :)

Comment: I suspect that trying to mess around with smart pointer lifespans is going to become too complicated. I would suggest rather a `class WorkerPair;` that has two `Worker` member variables if the intention is to have Workers be paired off. Especially if the partner relationship is supposed to be reciprocal.

Comment: Other than defining ```make_unique``` myself is there a way around this without using make_unique? I'm on C++11. Also, putting this ```m_partner(std::make_unique<Worker>(std::move(partner)))``` in the initialiser list gives me the error ```'Worker' does not refer to a value```.

Comment: @Neosapien Then `m_worker(new Worker(std::move(partner)))`? Should work for both smart and non-smart pointers. But note that you need to handle copying and such yourself if using non-smart pointers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Rabbit-hole :( . That throws ```call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'Worker'```

Comment: @Neosapien Just do it inside the constructor body then: `m_worker = std::unique_ptr<Worker>(new Worker(std::move(partner)));`.

Comment: Bingo. See this is why you should never judge a user by their username :). Thanks @Someprogrammerdude